# How React recognize clicking items?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, components

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import './Row.css';
import YouTube from 'react-youtube';
import movieTrailer from 'movie-trailer';

function Row(props){
    const imgBaseURL = 'http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/';
    const fetchBaseURL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3';
    
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
    const [videoURL, setVideoURL] = useState('');

    useEffect(async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`${fetchBaseURL}${props.fetchURL}`);
        const data = await response.json();
        setMovies(data.results);
        return data;
    }, [props.fetchURL]);

    const handleClick = (movie) => {
        console.log(movie);
    };

    return (
        <div>
           <h3 className="movie-header">{props.title}</h3>
           <div className="row_posters">
            {movies.map((movie) => {
                return (
                    <img 
                        onClick={() => handleClick(movie)} 
                        key={movie.id} 
                        className="row_poster" 
                        src={`${imgBaseURL}${props.isLargeRow? movie.poster_path: movie.backdrop_path}`}
                    />
                )
             })  
            }
           </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Row;
```

Here is one component that I created while building netflix-clone app. I want to cllick one movie poster and I wanna grab json object of that movie.  therefore I have used `onClick` attribute and put `{() => handleClick(movie)}` this peace of code. It actually passes the movie object that I am clicking. But I can't figure out how it happens. Does it execute map function again when I click on a poster. Or how it recognize that movie?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event and https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

map function is function that takes a dependency with function type

when you call map function on a list, for every item of that list, map function runs the function that you passed to its dependency and also it gives info of that list item, whenever it runs the passed function

for example

here we have a list of colors

```
const colors = ["red","green","blue","yellow"];
```

now we want to cal the map function over that list

```
colors.map(
  //here we would pass the function
  (color)=>{
     return <div>{color}</div>;
  }
)
```

we will get four `divs` that contain the list item strings, like so

`red`

`green`

`blue`

`yellow`

so we defined that whenever you run the passed function, return a div that contains the list colors

now we can define whenever that function gets called return a div that whenever user clicks on it, it shows an alert that contains the color of that div

```
colors.map(
  //here we would pass the function
  (color)=>{
     return <div onClick={()=>{alert(color)}}>click me to see my color}</div>;
  }
)
```

read more about map function in here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp

Answer (score 0):

The map function loops through each movie object and displays it as an image in the DOM using that JXS code you wrote inside.  Each of the images has an object of the movies it is displaying. So when you click it, the `console.log(movie)` displays that the movie object passed by the `{() => handleClick(movie)}` in that image.